# Filtering an array of objects by a set list price ranges and other options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```js
{
  "id":"3c97d11f-3feb-5af5-8092-b3f5c4a8257d",
  "name":"Ruffled striped organic cotton shirt",
  "price":215,
  "referralUrl":"link.com",
  "imageUrl":"//images.url",
  "imageHeight":3000,
  "imageWidth":2000,
  "imageSrcSet": [....],
  "imageSrcSetSizes":["(max-width: 667px) 100vw, 667px"],
  "created":"2020-11-01T22:37:17.927Z",
  "tags":[],
  "categories":["Clothes"],
  "colours":["Neutrals"],
  "shopResponsibly":[]
},
{
  ...,
  price:1000,
  ...
}
```

And I have a filter that loops through all the filters I have setup as follows:

```
const multiFilter = (item, condition) => {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(condition)
  return item.filter((eachObj) => {
    return filterKeys.every((eachKey) => {
      if (!condition[eachKey].length) {
        return true // passing an empty filter means that filter is ignored.
      }

      return condition[eachKey]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(eachObj[eachKey].toString().toLowerCase())
    })
  })
}
```

Now this works perfectly when my filters object is of single values and arrays, but I when I try to select a price filter the `condition[eachKey]` comes back as undefined and then the page fails. I'm certain it's to do with how I have my form fields values setup for prices and how they get pushed to the filters state object.

Here is how I have constructed my price filter HTML:

```
<form>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="prices"
                value='{"rangeFrom":0,"rangeTo":50}'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
              Up to &pound;50
            </label>

            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="prices"
                value='{"rangeFrom":50,"rangeTo":100}'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
              &pound;50 - &pound;100
            </label>

            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="prices"
                value='{"rangeFrom":100,"rangeTo":250}'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
              &pound;100 - &pound;250
            </label>

            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="prices"
                value='{"rangeFrom":250,"rangeTo":500}'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
              &pound;250 - &pound;500
            </label>

            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="prices"
                value='{"rangeFrom":500}'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
              &pound;500+
            </label>

            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="prices"
                value="all"
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
              All
            </label>
          </form>
```

This is my `handleChange` function:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.persist()

    const fieldname = e.target.name
    const options = [...filters[fieldname]]

    if (e.target.checked) {
      options.push(e.target.value)
    } else {
      let index = options.indexOf(e.target.value)
      options.splice(index, 1)
    }

    setFilters({ ...filters, [fieldname]: options })
  }
```

Which produces an object similar to:

```
{
    categories: ['cat1', 'cat'],
    colours: ['blue', 'red, 'green'],
    other: ['thing', 'foo'],
    price: ['{"rangeFrom":250,"rangeTo":500}']
}
```

I can't figure out how to modify the multiFilter function to accept the price array and for it to look at the `rangeFrom` and `rangeTo` values and filter the products price by the selected range.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.parse` to try and convert the filter values into an object, e.g. something like:

```js
const multiFilter = (items, condition) => {
    const filterKeys = Object.keys(condition);
    return items.filter(item => filterKeys.every(filterKey => {
        const filterValues = condition[filterKey];
        if (!filterValues.length) {
            return true // passing an empty filter means that filter is ignored.
        }

        const itemValue = item[filterKey];

        try {
            // Deal with object filter values
            return filterValues
                .map(JSON.parse)
                .some(({ rangeFrom, rangeTo }) => itemValue >= rangeFrom && itemValue <= rangeTo);

        } catch {
            // Deal with string filter values
            return filterValues.some(filterValue => 
                filterValue.toString().toLowerCase() === 
                itemValue.toString().toLowerCase()
            );
        }
    })
}
```

The downside of your apprach though, is that it's a little bit "brittle" - what happens if you want to introduce a new type of filter that checks the `created` date is between a range?

```
<label>
    <input
    type="radio"
    name="created"
    value='{"minDate":"2020-01-01","maxDate":"2021-01-01"}'
    onChange={handleChange}
    />
    Created in 2020
</label>
```

If this is a realistic possibility, then I'd be considering an entirely different approach - I'd probably make the whole thing data driven. For example, you could create some helper methods to create "filters", like this:

```js
const createPriceFilter = (label, minValue = null, maxValue = null) => {
  const apply = (item) => {
    if (minValue !== null && item.price < minValue) return false;
    if (maxValue !== null && item.price > maxValue) return false;
    return true;
  };

  return {
    label,
    isActive: false,
    apply
  };
};
```

Then you could use that helper method to create as many filters as you need:

```js
createPriceFilter("$100 - $200", 100, 200),
```

You could also have different types of filters - `dateFilter`, or `nameFilter` for example - just make sure they all have the same interface.

Now that you've got your filters, you could create a component that renders a filter, and responds to changes - here's a rudimentary filter that shows the label and an "Apply"/"Remove" button:

```
const Filter = ({ filter, onChange }) => {
  const handleChange = () => onChange(filter, !filter.isActive);
  const buttonText = filter.isActive ? "Remove" : "Apply";
  const className = `filter ${filter.isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`;

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <span>{filter.label}</span>
      <input type="button" onClick={handleChange} value={buttonText} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, to work out how to render your items, you just have to apply any filter that's marked as `isActive: true` to your list of items; something like:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState(FILTERS);

const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
  const activeFilters = filters.filter(f => f.isActive);

  return activeFilters.length > 0
    ? ITEMS.filter(item => activeFilters.every(f => f.apply(item)))
    : ITEMS;
}, [filters]);
```

[Here's a CodeSandbox showing it all in action](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-tharp-jlhfp?file=/src/App.js) - I threw it together quickly so don't be judging my terrible styling

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gerrod.

I have tried to implement your solution but it seems to not return any results upon selecting a price filter.

Would you have any suggestions to make implementing a similar filtering system that is less brittle?

I'm currently seeing some odd results appearing with the original filter code where some items are getting returned when they shouldn't be so I'm reconsidering my approach to this a whole so would really appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: @thomasbritton - using a data-driven approach to filters is probably better - check my updated answer 

Comment: thanks for the updates. it works for the most part, but following the new style for generating the filters, it falls down on when I want to select multiple different filters, for example I want to return all items which have been categorised with 'Gifts" and "Shoes" as well as a "price" and maybe some other filters such as "colours" etc. I've tried to change the `apply` function for the specific filter type but can't get them to marry up well and it ends up just filtering down to only the specific products which exactly match the data coming back from the API. Any ideas to achieve this?

Comment: It would all come down to how you compose your filters collection - in my CodeSandbox I did it very naively (using an array of all the active filters), but you could categorize your filters however you like. It might help if you put up a CodeSandbox demo that shows the problem?

Comment: I have forked your codesanbox @gerrod and added the data and to where to i have got to which shows the issue. the link is: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-beaver-oqhnx. The 'categories' key comes trhough as an array but I have changed that to be a string in my latest effort to see if I could wrangle that together. If possible to keep it an as array i think that would be better. Ultimately I'm trying to reach a faceted filter system which you usually find on ecommerce sites.

Comment: I think I get you; try this - https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-bas-rdi11 - If you select 'Bags' and 'Accessories' it shows products in either of those categories. I've also shown how you could add the concept of an 'exclusive' filter (e.g. you can only have one price range filter active) to show how you can build on this approach.

Comment: thanks for tha @gerrod, that is working exactly right now, thank you very much! Could you suggest a way to be able to group the specific type of filters into different sections on the UI please? For example https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2gj94rfxmg7spy/filters-ui.png?dl=0

Comment: Just split them up by the category (or add a new property on the filter for 'heading') - https://codesandbox.io/s/black-darkness-b8gc1